# Where does Firefox highlights get its images from?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Overall, I like the new Firefox "highlights" feature of the New Tab Page. For most pages that appear there, the first image on the page or a high-res favicon becomes the image on the highlights badge. But for a few websites, this is not the case.

[image: Example Highlights Entries]

I took this screenshot after browsing to

- http://biotropica.org/photos-from-the-field_pegueroespelta/ and
- https://www.uidaho.edu/engr/departments/cme/our-people/faculty/james-moberly.aspx

Neither page contains the image shown on the badge. I've also checked the network tab in developer tools, and these images don't appear as requests there, either.

Where is Firefox pulling these images from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is coming from the meta tag.

The same image is used when you share the website on facebook.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="share-image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: It’s known as the OpenGraph protocol. More information can be found at http://ogp.me/